# Is there a way to know the variable name that URL Dispatcher pass to view?

Tags: python, django, url, dispatcher

i dont know if this is possible, but i will explain what i want try !

I made a Context Processor that will load some user information.
I need know, in this context processor, if there is a variable named "group" in the vars list that will be passed to my view, and if is, i will load up more things.

The processor only receive a REQUEST object, and i think with ONLY this is not possible.

But, with REQUEST_PATH (from request) i could make some magic (w/ urls.py) and find the exact view and variable that was choose by django. Is there a simple way to do this (or maybe ... a way ? :D ) ?

---- solution ----

The solution (using what yasar11732 say) is something like this:

```
x = resolve(request.META["PATH_INFO"])
if 'group_name' in x.kwargs
    do_domething()
```

Thanks ! :)

Comment: Don't use `has_key`; it's deprecated. Just use `if 'group_name' in x.kwargs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see: [resolve()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#resolve) It does exactly what are you trying to do. Be aware that this function throws an 404 exception if it doesn't find a match, so be ready to catch it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just add this in selectively on a per-view basis? Then you could do something like this:

```
def group_processor(request):
    # ...

def some_view(request, user, group=None):
    # ...
    processors = [group_processor] if group else []
    context = RequestContext(request, {}, processors)
    return render_to_response("my_template.html", context_instance=context)
```